# Trying to change for value for a simple unit converter (first time working with the DOM in JS)

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

Hi guys I am trying to create as a simple degrees to Fahrenheit converter with Js and some DOM manipulation. I am using google chrome. The problem seems to be that `addEventListener` isn't working anyway here is the code:

```
var button = document.getElementById('degreesToFahrinheit')

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var value = document.getElementById('DtF_in').value;
    var input = document.getElementById('DtF_in');
    var newValue = value * 9/5 + 32;
    input.setAttribute('value', 'hello world!')
});
```

and my incredibly simple html :

```
<button id="degreestoFahrinheit">Convert</button>
    <input id="DtF_in"></input>
 <script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Thanks so much for the help in advance guys. Note hello world is intentionally there in my crappy efforts to see the problem. `newValue` is supposed to be in its place.

Comment: You have one small typo - check your html -> button id should be: degreesToFahrinheit  (To - uppercase). P.S. Always check console for errors - it saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

See the "vanilla js" entry on this site: http://n12v.com/2-way-data-binding/
There's a degree to fahrenheit converter